# Use parLapply for nlminb

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Although there are several questions arleady to parLapply I couldn`t find an answer to my current task...

I try to use parLapply on a List of B bootstrap sample matrices. Depending on a chosen transformation (within or first-difference) I use nlminb( ) to maximize a log likelihood.

**The problem** if I run the code, the cores can not find SFM.within OR SFM.firstDiff.
SFM.within & SFM.firstDiff are complex functions in my package fepsfrontieR.

**Question**: How can I provide the clusters my functions?

Please find below the code. Please excuse the missing example data, as I believe  that this question can be answered from an experienced parLapply user easily...

```
no_of_cores = detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(no_of_cores, type="PSOCK")


clusterExport(cl, c("myPar", "lowerInt", "Time", "N", "bootListMat", "mu", "optim", "K", "R", "method", "cumTime"))

if (method == "within"){
    bootEstimates <- parLapply (cl = cl, bootListMat, function(x) nlminb(lower = lowerInt,
                                                      start = myPar,
                                                      Time = Time,
                                                      N = N,
                                                      xv = as.matrix (x[, 2:(2+K-1)]),
                                                      y = as.matrix (x[, 1]),
                                                      z = as.matrix (x[, (2+K):cols]),
                                                      mu = mu,
                                                      optim = optim,
                                                      K = K, R = R,
                                                      objective = SFM.within,
                                                      cumTime = cumTime
                                                      )$par)  # we want only the estimates   } else {
    bootEstimates <- parLapply (cl = cl, bootListMat, function(x) nlminb(lower = lowerInt,
                                                             start = myPar,  # TBD by Rouven
                                                             Time = Time,
                                                             N = N,
                                                             xv = as.matrix (x[, 2:(2+K-1)]),
                                                             y = as.matrix (x[, 1]),
                                                             z = as.matrix (x[, (2+K):cols]),
                                                             mu = mu,
                                                             optim = optim,
                                                             K = K, R = R,
                                                             objective = SFM.firstDiff,
                                                             cumTime = cumTime
                                                             )$par)  # we want only the estimates
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code evaluated by the "workers" in the cluster (background R sessions), depends on your package fepsfrontieR, then you need to attach that package in each of the workers (just as you do in your main R session). So, try:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(fepsfrontieR))
```

Comment: Thanks HenrikB. Worked. But i had to add clusterExport(..., **envir = environment()** ) to make it finally running :-)

Comment: It sounds like a hack to have to export the full enclosing environment and you might export way more than you need (which can be costly). I would try to identify each global that you need to export (e.g. from error messages) and manually export them.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use `bootEstimates <- future.apply::future_lapply(bootListMat, FUN = ...)` to parallelize - the advantage is that it takes care of globals automatically.  (Disclaimer: I'm the author of the future framework).

Comment: I will try that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to export the function as well to the cluster